# Node.js- Can't get React browser to open when I run 'npm run start' or MongoDB to start when I run 'mongod'

Tags: node.js, git, mongodb, reactjs, github

[image]

I've been having issues with a project I'm working on. I couldn't push or pull code from Git because of merge conflicts which I couldn't find them all so I thought it would be easier to just clone the latest commit from the repo and manually put my code in but when I cloned it I have an error when I run 'npm start' to start the react browser, it doesn't open and webpack doesn't come up and also when I run 'mongod' I get an error about it already possibly running an instance but nothing else is running and even when I kill it and re-run it I get the same error.

I just ran '`git stash`' and '`git reset --hard HEAD`' and had the response '`HEAD is now at 32c5fb3 visual changed`' but when I try to run '`npm run start`' the react browser doesn't start and 'mongod' still doesn't run.

I'm trying to get the latest commit to the repo to work with react-router and mongodb.

This error is after I deleted the node_modules folder and ran '`npm i`' in the root,
Then went into the 'client' directory and ran '`npm run start`' to start React

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your node modules are not completely installed. Try deleting `node modules` again and run `npm install`